# Alternative to dbms_output.putline

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am creating a dynamic query in a procedure and now want to see it through `dbms_output.putline`, but my query contains more than 255 characters.

How to view the query?

What are the alternates of `dbms_output.putline`?

Comment: `dbms_output.putline` does not have a limit of 255 characters. Why do you think that?

Comment: dbms_output.put_line has limitation of 255 characters 
per line.

Answer (score 4):

There's a little bit of confusion going on.

In Oracle 9i `dbms_output.put_line` is [limited to 255 characters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96612/d_outpu2.htm#1000446). This restriction was [removed in 10g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#i1000105) and is similarly not present in [Oracle 11g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_output.htm#i1000105).

You have tagged your question [oracle10g](/questions/tagged/oracle10g), which means that you're limited to 32,767 bytes, the standard PL/SQL maximum.

Comment: +1, I didn't know about the limit in 9i (that is soooo long ago)

Comment: I didn't know that the restriction had been lifted in 10g until I saw your comment and went looking :-). I don't really have occasion to print really long things. Thank you for fixing my fat fingered 1 @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I am getting this error in oracle 10g ORA-20000: ORU-10028: line length overflow, limit of 255 chars per line...

Answer (score 2):

try mess around something like

```
create or replace procedure custom_output(in_string in varchar2 )
is 

   out_string_in long default in_string; 
   str_len number; 
   loop_count number default 0; 

begin 

   str_len := length(out_string_in);

   while loop_count < str_len
   loop 
      dbms_output.put_line( substr( out_string_in, loop_count +1, 255 ) ); 
      loop_count := loop_count +255; 
   end loop; 

end;

/
```