# How to execute dynamic sql into cursor in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I have problem with execute dynamic sql statement into sys_refcursor in my stored procedure.
I have looked in documentation and I think that I build my procedure properly, but I still do not know why error occurs.
Please look below, what I created:

```
CREATE TABLE REKOM_CROSS_PROM (
      LINIA_PROD VARCHAR2(20), 
      ID_REKOM_OFERTA VARCHAR2(20),
      PRICE NUMBER,
      MAX_PRICE NUMBER
    );
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE prodType AS OBJECT (
p_line VARCHAR2(20)
,p_price NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE prodTypeList IS TABLE OF prodType;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc (prodLines IN prodTypeList ,rekom OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
v_pLine VARCHAR2(20);
v_query VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  v_query := 'SELECT ID_REKOM_OFERTA FROM REKOM_CROSS_PROM WHERE 
LINIA_PROD=NULL';
FOR i IN 1 .. prodLines.COUNT
    LOOP
        v_pLine := prodLines(i).p_line;
        v_query := v_query || ' UNION ALL SELECT ID_REKOM_OFERTA FROM 
                    REKOM_CROSS_PROM WHERE LINIA_PROD=''' || v_pLine || '''';
    END LOOP;
OPEN rekom FOR v_query;
END my_proc;
/
```

And when I want to call the procedure, error occur.

```
set serveroutput on
    declare
    type1 prodTypeList := prodTypeList(prodType('test1',1), prodType('test2', 20));
    rc SYS_REFCURSOR;
    row varchar2(200);
BEGIN
    MY_PROC(type1, rc);
    fetch rc into row;
    while (rc%found) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(row);
end loop;
close rc;
end;
```

I get the message:

**ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 1000000 bytes**

***Cause:    The stored procedure 'raise_application_error'
           was called which causes this error to be generated.**

***Action:   Correct the problem as described in the error message or contact
           the application administrator or DBA for more information.**

Can sombody help me to resolve the problem?

Comment: That error just means you're exceeding the dbms_output buffer. How many rows are you expecting the constructed query to find? (And why are you constructing a query like that instead of using a collection of values in the query? Also: `=NULL` is never true, you need `IS NULL`.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase dbms\_output buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476568/how-to-increase-dbms-output-buffer)

Comment: @AlexPoole I expect only 3 rows. Im not using collection because I will add additional columns to REKOM_CROSS_PROM (price, max_price number) and after I will change WHERE clause to add: 'AND p_price BETWEEN PRICE AND MAX_PRICE. So when I add this, I couldn't use collection like this: WHERE LINIA_PROD IN (SELECT p_line FROM prodLines)

Comment: I don't see why you can't still use a collection, but maybe I'm missing something. Off-topic, anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an infinite loop. That means you're calling `dbms_output.put_line` forever - or until it runs out of buffer space, and throws that exception.

```
BEGIN
  MY_PROC(type1, rc);
  -- fetch first row from result set
  fetch rc into row;
  -- check if last fetch found something - always true
  while (rc%found) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(row);
  end loop;
  close rc;
end;
```

Every time around the loop you're checking the result of that first fetch, which stays true (assuming there is any data). You need to fetch each time round the loop:

```
BEGIN
  MY_PROC(type1, rc);
  -- fetch first row from result set
  fetch rc into row;
  -- check if last fetch found something
  while (rc%found) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(row);
    -- fetch next row from result set
    fetch rc into row;
  end loop;
  close rc;
end;
```

Or perhaps more commonly, only fetch inside the loop, and stop when nothing is found, using `%notfound` rather than `%found`:

```
BEGIN
  MY_PROC(type1, rc);
  loop
    -- fetch row from result set
    fetch rc into row;
    -- check if last fetch found something
    exit when rc%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(row);
  end loop;
  close rc;
end;
```

---

Not related to your current issue, but the predicate `WHERE LINIA_PROD=NULL` is never true; null isn't equal to (or not equal to) anything else. You need to use `WHERE LINIA_PROD IS NULL` instead.

Comment: I didn't notice it :D Thanks for your eagle eye :)