# DBMS_OUTPUT buffer size (client or database side)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, dbms-output

I use SQL Developer to run queries on Oracle databases, the DBMS_OUTPUT buffer size is set by default (20000) in SQL Developer.

When I run the query against DEV database, everything is OK.
When I run the same query against Production database, the same SQL Developer session, I get error :

```
ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 10000 bytes.
```

Have you an idea why ? There is any limitation set on database side.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476568/how-to-increase-dbms-output-buffer may be this will help you

Comment: The buffer size is set to 20000, why my query is limited to 10000?

Comment: DECLARE BEGIN dbms_output.enable(NULL); -- Disables the limit of DBMS -- Your print here ! END; try to disabling the limit, if still you have error then the client you are using i.e sql developer having the conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't reveal how exactly you call procedures from `dbms_output` package so I can just guess. In fact I got same error and found a cause in my case which might be of course different than yours.

In my case I had a buffer of length 10000 (in PLSQL Developer, which is not important here) and I called only the `dbms_output.put` procedure, not `dbms_output.put_line`. The `put` procedure keeps filling buffer and does not flush it, even if string argument contains newline character.

Compare these two attempts of writing 1001 lines of ten-characters-long string (nine visible + line terminator):

```sql
begin
  dbms_output.enable(10000);
  for i in 1..1001 loop
    dbms_output.put('123456789' || chr(10)); -- fails here
  end loop;
end;
```

vs.

```
begin
  dbms_output.enable(10000);
  for i in 1..1001 loop
    dbms_output.put_line('123456789'); -- works
  end loop;
end;
```

The first example fails with `ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 10000 bytes` because it tries to put 10010 chars into buffer.

(The real story from which this minimalistic example was synthetized was printing package source code from `dba_source` table. Every line of source source code in `text` column is terminated by newline character which must be trimmed before sending into `put_line` - without trimming it would be doubled; sending text into sole `put` method would cause the buffer trouble.)